# PHP Class Parent Instance (Singleton)

Tags: php

The scenario is this

```
class a
{
  public $val;
}

class b extends a
{

}

class c extends b
{

}

$one = new b();
$one->val = "a value";

$other = new c();

echo $other->val;
// wanted 'a value', got ''
```

So the result i need here is: "a value", but of course is blank.

What i need is that the 'a' class to always be used as an instance in 'b'. So whenever i  use a class that extends the 'b', the parent 'a' class to be inhereted as an instance.

Comment: OOPs is not clear in you mind. Object has it's own property and bounded with only that object.

Comment: declare class property as static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the php manual on the static keyword it gives an example of exactly what you are trying to do. You can read about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Here is the example code they use.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooStatic() {
        return parent::$my_static;
    }
}


print Foo::$my_static . "\n";

$foo = new Foo();
print $foo->staticValue() . "\n";
print $foo->my_static . "\n";      // Undefined "Property" my_static 

print $foo::$my_static . "\n";
$classname = 'Foo';
print $classname::$my_static . "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0

print Bar::$my_static . "\n";
$bar = new Bar();
print $bar->fooStatic() . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$other = new c();` is actually creating a new instance, it is not possible.
but if you declare val as Static member, you will have the result that you want.

```
    <?
class a
{
  public static $val;
}

class b extends a
{

}

class c extends b
{

}

$one = new b();
a::$val = "a value";



echo c::$val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it without Inheritance:

```
class A
{
    public $foo;
}
class B {
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
class C {
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B($a);
$c = new C($a);
$b->a->val = 'one value';
echo $c->a->val;
```

If you dont like having to fetch $a first to get to val, you could assign by reference

```
class A
{
    public $foo;
}
class B {
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->val = &$a->val;
    }
}
class C {
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->val = &$a->val;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B($a);
$c = new C($a);
$b->val = 'one value';
echo $c->val;
```

Though personally I find the first approach more maintainable and clear.

Comment: I dont want to use it by static. Also i cannot use it like that because there are a lot of classes that will use the parent $a, some of them in functions and i cannot use global everywhere.

Comment: @keepwalking Sorry, but I don't understand. There is neither a static, nor a global anywhere in the examples above.